# Getting the date of the first occurrence of value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

new to excel and need help with the following sample data.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7xKz.png)

From the data given, I want to subtract the dates for e.g.

N/O: 123, it will be B2-B4

And for N/O: 125, it will be B5-B6

And for N/O: 128, it will be 1.

I have though of creating a flag to check the occurrence of false but unable to piece it properly, please help me if possible. Thanks!

Comment: You should try something yourself. You could do this with a pivot table using Min date and Max date.

Comment: Do you want a formula to get the column C values you have on your sample? Or for every 123 on column A you want the result B2-B4??

Comment: @SJR I have tried, but unable to get it to work. Therefore seeking help.

Comment: @Pspl Got the correct answer below, thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for,

[image]

Enter the below formula in `C2` and drag it down,

```
=IF(A2<>A3,IF(INDEX(A:B,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A2,0),2)-B2=0,1,INDEX(A:B,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A2,0),2)-B2),"")
```

Let me know if you need any help or modifications.

Comment: Hi Shiva, thanks so much for your help! This is correct.

Comment: @RollIWSP Thats great !!

Comment: Hi Shiva, possible to help me add one more condition? Whereby if the results are more than 30, display >30 in the box. Thanks!

Comment: @RollIWSP Try this...  `=IF(A2<>A3,IF(INDEX(A:B,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A2,0),2)-B2=0,1,IF(INDEX(A:B,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A2,0),2)-B2>30,">30",INDEX(A:B,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A2,0),2)-B2)),"")`

Comment: Thanks! But somehow unable to work. Received this error: http://imgur.com/a/RKzl4